# Alternative of ArpRetryCount in CentOS

Tags: linux, tcp, arp

ArpRetryCount Implemented by Microsoft and the following is its descritption :

> Determines how many times TCP sends an Address Request Packet for its
>   own address when the service is installed. This is known as a
>   gratuitous Address Request Packet. TCP sends a gratuitous Address
>   Request Packet to determine whether the IP address to which it is
>   assigned is already in use on the network....[more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957526.aspx)

What is the alternative of this technique with Linux based on RedHAT (like CentOS) ?

Answer (score 1):

Good IP address management?

Linux doesn't test if an IP address is already in use in the way that Windows does.

RedHat/CentOS uses `dhclient` as it's default DHCP client which also doesn't check if an IP address it's received from the DHCP server is already in use. It (probably) assumes that the DHCP server has been correctly configured in the first place.

You could possibly install [`garp`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/garp) to carry out a similar procedure, but you'd have to write it into the networking scripts. If you did, then the equivalent of `ArpRetryCount` would be the `-c` option.